# Select Count() of Values for specific column Names

Tags: sql

I currently have a table with total of 3503 records and I want to find Albums in which has more than 12 tracks listed per album. In the table,

```
albumId   Artist   TrackName
   1        A         Joy
   1        A         Test
   1        A         Lift
   4        B         Unknown
   4        B         Bill
   6        C         Jaxx
```

Comment: Do a GROUP BY. Use HAVING.

Answer (score 2):

Try something like:

```
select albumId, count(1) as tally 
from albums
group by albumId
having count(1) > 12
order by albumId
```

See [here](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_having.asp)

Answer (score 0):

SELECT  COUNT (albumId) as Albums FROM MyTable GROUP BY albumId HAVING COUNT(albumId)>1; replace Mytable to your table name.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to apply [GROUP BY](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sql-group-by/) on albumId, it helps to make group of albums and then apply [HAVING](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_having.asp), on count of albumId, it helps to filter records as per your condition ( like here you want to filter for more than 12 tracks.). You may try below query, I tested this on [MYSQL](https://www.mysql.com/).

```
SELECT albumId FROM `albums`
GROUP by albumId
HAVING COUNT(albumId) > 12
```

You may use an [ORDER BY](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-order-by/) to sort albums in ascending or descending order, if required. Like below

```
SELECT albumId FROM `albums`
GROUP by albumId
HAVING COUNT(albumId) > 3
ORDER by albumId
```